# Moving media files with specific language into specific folders

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am currently trying to figure out how I can automatically move all Mediafiles into specific folders once they appear in my folder C:\Media\

What I have so far:
To detect which language my media file is I want to use ffprobe.exe. 
This command is outputing the first audio streams language:

```
ffprobe.exe "C:Media\test.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
```

This is the output:

```
1|eng
```

This Mediafile should be moved automatically to the folder C:\Media\English.

How can I achieve that in Windows 10? Also how can I have it running all the time so whenever some media file is in that folder it will automatically be moved ?

Sometimes the media file is not directly in C:\Media\ sometimes it is in a subfolder. How can I make sure that also subfolders are searched through?

I never used scripting language on Windows before. What scripting language is the correct one for my purpose?

_
_
_

EDIT Output:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.805]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\salexes>FOR /R "C:\Media\"  %_ IN (*.mkv) DO @(
More?   ECHO.  Checking: %~f_
More?   ECHO. Running [ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1]
More?   FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=|" %A IN ('
More?     C:\Media\ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
More?   ') DO @(
More?     ECHO. FOR /F Loop returned [%%A]
More?     IF NOT EXIST "C:\Media\%A" (
More?       MD "C:\Media\%A" )
More?     ECHO. Moving "%~f_" TO: "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
More?     MOVE /Y "%~f_" "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
More?   )
More? )
  Checking: C:\Media\TestMKV3.mkv
 Running [ffprobe.exe "C:\Media\TestMKV3.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1]
  Checking: C:\Media\TestSubFolder\TestMKV1.mkv
 Running [ffprobe.exe "C:\Media\TestSubFolder\TestMKV1.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1]
  Checking: C:\Media\TestSubFolder2\TestMKV2.mkv
 Running [ffprobe.exe "C:\Media\TestSubFolder2\TestMKV2.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1]

C:\Users\salexes>
```

EDIT 2 UPDATED SCRIPT:
OUTPUT:

```
C:\Media>FOR /R "C:\Media\"  %_ IN (*.mkv) DO @(
More?   ECHO.  Checking: %~f_
More?   ECHO. Running [ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0]
More?   ECHO.
More?   ECHO.===========
More?   ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0
More?   ECHO.===========
More?   ECHO.
More?   FOR /F "Tokens=*" %A IN ('
More?     ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0
More?   ') DO @(
More?     ECHO. FOR /F Loop returned
More?     ECHO. "%A"
More?     IF NOT EXIST "C:\Media\%A" (
More?        MD "C:\Media\%A" )
More?     ECHO. Moving "%~f_" TO: "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
More?       MOVE /Y "%~f_" "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
More?   )
More? )
  Checking: C:\Media\TestMKV3.mkv
 Running [ffprobe.exe "C:\Media\TestMKV3.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0]

===========
1,eng
===========

  Checking: C:\Media\TestSubFolder\TestMKV1.mkv
 Running [ffprobe.exe "C:\Media\TestSubFolder\TestMKV1.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0]
.
===========
1,fr
===========
.
  Checking: C:\Media\TestSubFolder2\TestMKV2.mkv
 Running [ffprobe.exe "C:\Media\TestSubFolder2\TestMKV2.mkv" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0]
.
===========
1,eng
===========
.

C:\Media>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I assume all of the files you wish to check are `.mkv`?

You can loop the files in their Folders using a `For /R` Loop to loop the files in C:\Media and any subdirectories.

it would be much easier to just move the files into directories which match whatever language is returned, so `eng` instead of `english`.

If you need to have the full names for some other code it would still be easiest to just `MKLINK /J "C\Media\English" "C\Media\Eng"` by hand for all of the languages you care to have these full names for.

You can run this directly in the CMD Prompt by pasting it in:

```
FOR /R "C:\Media\"  %_ IN (*.mkv) DO @(
  ECHO.  Checking: %~f_
  ECHO. Running [ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1]
  FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=|" %A IN ('
    ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
  ') DO @(
    ECHO. FOR /F Loop returned [%A]
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Media\%A" (
      MD "C:\Media\%A" )
    ECHO. Moving "%~f_" TO: "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
    MOVE /Y "%~f_" "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
  )
)
```

Also how can I have it running all the time so whenever some media file is in that folder it will automatically be moved ?

Set up a scheduled Task using Task Scheduler, and have the script run every X minutes, also make sure you set the task to not run i the previous command was still running and put a limit on how long it can run, maybe 30 minutes.

Always use "New task" not New basic task, select "Run with Highest Privileges" Checkbox, and select the newest version of windows available in the drop-down.

```
REM Script: SortMKVs.cmd

@( SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
)

FOR /R "C:\Media\"  %%_ IN (*.mkv) DO @(
  ECHO.  Checking: %%~f_
  ECHO. Running [ffprobe.exe "%%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1]
  FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=|" %%A IN ('
    ffprobe.exe "%%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of compact=p=0:nk=1
  ') DO (
    ECHO. FOR /F Loop returned [%%A]
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Media\%%A" (
      MD "C:\Media\%%A" )
    ECHO. Moving "%%~f_" TO: "C:\Media\%%A\%%~nx_"
    MOVE /Y "%%~f_" "C:\Media\%%A\%%~nx_"
  )
)

( ENDLOCAL
  GOTO :EOF
)
```

### Edit Direct Method for Testing v2:

```
FOR /R "C:\Media\"  %_ IN (*.mkv) DO @(
  ECHO.  Checking: %~f_
  ECHO. Running [ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0]
  ECHO.
  ECHO.===========
  ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0
  ECHO.===========
  ECHO.
  FOR /F "Tokens=*" %A IN ('
    ffprobe.exe "%~f_" -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams 1 -v 0 -of csv=p=0
  ') DO @(
    ECHO. FOR /F Loop returned 
    ECHO. "%A"
    IF NOT EXIST "C:\Media\%A" (
      REM MD "C:\Media\%A" )
    ECHO. Moving "%~f_" TO: "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
    REM MOVE /Y "%~f_" "C:\Media\%A\%~nx_"
  )
)
```

Comment: Wow this is amazing! Yes I am just having mkv files. Will try it out immedeatly.
Just to be sure I understand the script correctly now, when it detects first language is lets say french, it would save the file to C:\Media\fr\ correct ?

Comment: I just used the ffprobe command on a file and it just returned: 1
Without anything else, so no language was detected, what does the script do in that case ?

Comment: And sorry for the third comment but do I need to save the script into some file before creating a task in task scheduler ?
Thank you again for all the help!

Comment: @Salexes Yes that is how it should work, assuming that "FR" is what is returned by the ffprobe command. In the case that no response is returned it should essentially remain in the same directory.  If you want to run int in Scheduler I would save it a a .cd file but you also have to double up the `%` signs on the `For` loop variables, I'll just post that version at the end of the answer fo ryou.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I really appreciate it! I was just able to try the script you created (the first one) and this is the only output I get & the files do not get moved. See here: https://pastebin.com/raw/v2zgSmNh

When I check the files manually
TestMKV1 returns: 1|eng
TeskMKV2 returns 1|fr
TestMKV3 returns 1|eng

Comment: @Salexes Can you paste the literal output inside code tags for me?  I am amending the script to print the command it will execute and execute it outside the FOR /F loop once as well to see what it returns since the issue seems to be the FOR /F loop is not getting the expected output from your command.

Comment: I just edited my question and posted the output from the the first script

Comment: Strange, that seems to indicate the command isn't returning anything to the for loop.  Try editing this `FOR /F "Tokens=2 Delims=|" %A` to this `FOR /F "Tokens=*" %A` and place a `REM ` in front of `MD` and in front of the `Move` command so we just have the echos

Comment: I just did that but I get the exact same out put as in my edited question. (I tried to move this disscussion to a chat but sadly, i still have not enouhg reputation to do so, so for now we have to continue everything in the comments)

Comment: @Salexes  Yeah I would move it to chat if I could but it won;t work from my side either unless you have a certain amount of rep. :(  From what you are seeing it looks liek the command is not executing inside the for loop, or just not returning any information, which is strange.  I will post again hoping to see the out put from the command directly

Comment: @Selexes Its a shame too because I am available now to chat if we could.  I have amended the script and place dit at the bottom to get some output, I looked up ffprobe and believe the CSV format may be better so I changed from compact to CSV.

Comment: Just 7 reputation is missing. Lets see if I can build 7 reputation quikcly. I just tried the code you updated in your post and edited my question and pasted the output there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201893/discussion-between-salexes-and-ben-personick).

Comment: Checking now! Sorry was traveling the last few days.